# Interior Extremum Theorem and discontinuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying real analysis with Bartle & Sherbert's *Introduction to Real Analysis*. There is the following theorem:

**Interior Extremum Theorem:** Let $c$ be an interior point of the interval $I$ at which $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ has a relative extremum. If the derivative of $f$ at $c$ exists, then $f'(c)=0$.

The proof is easy to follow, and note that there is no mention about the continuity of $f$ on $I$. But then this corollary follows:

**Corollary:** Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on an interval $I$ and suppose that $f$ has a relative extremum at an interior point $c$ of $I$. Then either the derivative of $f$ at $c$ does not exist, or it is equal to zero.

It is certainly true, but why you have to make the further assumption that $f$ is continuous? Can't we say from the previous theorem that it is true for discontinuous functions as well?

Comment: You're right; the continuity assumption is not needed. Most likely, it is a "typo".

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks a lot. That answers my question, so maybe you can post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; the continuity assumption is not needed. Most likely, it is a "typo".